# Remove 0 values ​from a linear regression in ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, linear-regression

I have a linear regression but the table has 0 values ​​and I need to remove them from the graph, I have tried to replace the 0 values ​​with NA but it gives an error. Any solution?

```
gr1<-dia28 %>% 
dplyr::select(N_descargas, Temp_media_FIRMS,Temp_FIRMS_maxima ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -N_descargas) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = N_descargas, y = value,color=name)) +
  geom_point()+
  guides(col=guide_legend(""))+
  stat_smooth(aes(), method="lm", formula=y ~ x,se=FALSE) +
  theme_light()+
  ylab("Temperatura(ºC)") +
  xlab("Número de descargas") +
  ggtitle("DIA 28")+
  scale_color_hue(labels = c("Temperatura maxima", "Temperatura media"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox(hjust = 1,
 vjust = 1,
 halign = 0.5,
 valign = 0.5,
 lineheight = 1,
 linetype = 1,
 face ="bold.italic",
size = 14,
 fill = "#c5c9c8",
r = unit(1, "pt"),
 width = unit(1, "npc"),
height = unit(0.4, "inch")),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"))+
stat_cor(aes(label = ..r.label..),
 method = "pearson",
 label.x=20 ,
 label.y = c(230,270, size=5))+
  stat_regline_equation(label.x=28 ,
label.y =c(230,270,size=5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the zero values are in the variable `N_descargas`, all you need to do before plotting is a `filter()` call, like so:

```
gr1<-dia28 %>% 
dplyr::select(N_descargas, Temp_media_FIRMS,Temp_FIRMS_maxima ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -N_descargas) %>%
  filter(N_descargas != 0) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = N_descargas, y = value,color=name)) + ...
```